# How to change the FB login button with own image

Tags: php

I am trying to change the default FB login button with the one I would like to use.  Here is the code FB generate for me by default when creating a FB login:

`<div class="fb-login-button" data-show-faces="true" data-width="200" data-max-rows="1"></div>`

My code is in PHP and html5.  Is there a way I a change the default fb-login-button with my personal one?

Answer (score 1):

Not via PHP, no; because the Facebook stuff is added by a client-script that Facebook includes in your page by its bootstrap script.

The only way to change it is by writing your own script that changes your page's DOM after Facebook's scripts have run, this way you can modify the Facebook button and other stuff; but be careful because Facebook can modify their scripts without telling you so your patch script might not work.